# How to up content above bottom bar?

Tags: android

I want make my top status bar transparent but I got problem:[image]

This is my theme(v21):

```
<style name="PhTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And this I use for window (code from... stackOverFlow):

```
public static void setFullScreen(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

This method I call in `onCreate()` after `super.onCreate()`.

So - **how to up content above bottom bar?** (With back button)

Comment: refer this https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this item also in your v21 style theme

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

and use this method

```
public static int getSoftButtonsBarSizePort(Activity activity) {
    // getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
        int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        if (realHeight > usableHeight)
            return realHeight - usableHeight;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```